# JavaScript refer for special characters except angular brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I am facing trouble with JavaScript regex to match all characters except <> and {}. Can anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do `[^{}<>]+`, which matches all characters, except for those in the square brackets, being `{}` and `<>`. Here's a snippet:

```js
var re = /[^{}<>]+/g;

// {} and <> are not matched here
console.log("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()-=_+?.,/\|{}<>".match(re));
```

Comment: I would prefer a white list rather than specifying a set of blacklisted characters.

Comment: Why @Sujay? Blacklist seems more practical, what's your usecase?

Comment: Simple reason for that being I don't want to allow any other characters which are not there in the key board. For ex: copyright symbol, other language characters etc. I just want a complete control on the list of characters allowed

Comment: @Sujay You can do `[chars_allowed]+`. If you want all US keyboard characters: `[\x00-\x7F]+`.